# Pythonic Way to Solve this Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I've been thinking on this problem, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I want to solve a matrix with three equations with unknowns x, y, z so they all equal the same number.

Lets say my equations are:

```
x + 3 = A
y(2y - 2) = 2A
z(4z - 1) = A
```

So I can construct a matrix looking like:

```
[(X + 3) , 0      ,       0] [0]   [A]
[ 0      ,(2y - 2),       0] [y] = [2A]
[ 0 ,    ,       0, (4z -1)] [z]   [A]
```

I know [numpy has a linear algebra](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve) but that is only when the answer (A) is already known.

My question is, would I have to construct a loop to brute force the answer of (A) or is there a more pythonic way of answering these series of equations?

Comment: Well, I think basic linear algebra methods are out since your system of equations isn't linear :-)

Comment: I think you want a [1] in that first entry of x where x is coming from Ax=b. I don't believe there is symbolic algebra in numpy, but that is what you need because your solution will likely have an A in it. Many symbolic math packages will be able to do what you want, but I don't think numpy is going to get you very far. I've never used it, but: http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear algebra can only solve for multiples of your variables, not powers (that is why it is called **linear**, ie the equation for a straight line, `Ax + By + Cz = 0`).

For this set of equations you can use the quadratic formula to solve in terms of a:

```
x + 3 = a            =>       x = a - 3


y * (y - 1) = a      =>       y**2 - y - a = 0

                              y = (1 +/- (1 + 4*a) ** 0.5) / 2

                                = 0.5 +/- (0.25 + a) ** 0.5

                                (a >= -0.25  for real roots)


z * (4*z - 1) = a    =>       4 * z**2 - z - a = 0

                              z = (1 +/- (1 + 16*a) ** 0.5) / 8

                                = 0.125 +/- (0.015625 + 0.25*a) ** 0.5

                                (a >= -0.0625  for real roots)
```

then

```
def solve(a):
    assert a >= -0.625, "No real solution"

    x = a - 3

    yoffs = (0.25 * a) ** 0.5
    ylo = 0.5 - yoffs
    yhi = 0.5 + yoffs

    zoffs = (0.015625 + 0.25 * a) ** 0.5
    zlo = 0.125 - zoffs
    zhi = 0.125 + zoffs

    return [
        (x, ylo, zlo),
        (x, ylo, zhi),
        (x, yhi, zlo),
        (x, yhi, zhi)
    ]
```

Comment: "This is not a linear system" is also something I should have put in my answer.  Shame on me :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns.  You have a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns: x, y, z and A.

That means your answer will be parameterized on A, because you do not have enough equations to solve for all unknowns.

Solving a general [system of polynomial equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations) can be done by the so-called Groebner basis approach, which is what [sympy uses](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/polysys.py#L101).  Here is a snippet on how to use the library to solve this or similar problems:

```
from sympy.solvers.polysys import solve_poly_system
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, A

f1 = x + 3 - A
f2 = y * (2 * y - 2) - 2 * A
f3 = z * (4 * z - 1) - A

solve_poly_system([f1, f2, f3], x, y, z)
# Outputs:
# [(A - 3, -sqrt(4*A + 1)/2 + 1/2, -sqrt(16*A + 1)/8 + 1/8),
# (A - 3, -sqrt(4*A + 1)/2 + 1/2, sqrt(16*A + 1)/8 + 1/8),
# (A - 3, sqrt(4*A + 1)/2 + 1/2, -sqrt(16*A + 1)/8 + 1/8),
# (A - 3, sqrt(4*A + 1)/2 + 1/2, sqrt(16*A + 1)/8 + 1/8)]
```

As you can see, the result requires to fix the value of `A` to be fully determined.